# How to calculate last business day of the month in Korn Shell?

Tags: date, ksh

I've seen this question answered in other languages but not the Korn Shell.  I need to prevent a script from being run on the last business day of the month (we can assume M-F are business days, ignore holidays).

Comment: See my edit. I added a version that doesn't require `date -d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function works in Bash, Korn shell and zsh, but it requires a `date` command (such as GNU `date`) that has the -d option:

```
function lbdm { typeset lbdm ldm dwn m y; (( m = $1 + 1 )); if [[ $m = 13 ]]; then  m=1; (( y = $2 + 1 )); else y=$2; fi; ldm=$(date -d "$m/1/$y -1 day"); dwn=$(date -d "$ldm" +%u);if [[ $dwn = 6 || $dwn = 7 ]]; then ((offset = 5 - $dwn)); lbdm=$(date -d "$ldm $offset day"); else lbdm=$ldm; fi; echo $lbdm; }
```

Run it like this:

```
$ lbdm 10 2009
Fri Oct 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009
```

Here is a demo script broken into separate lines and with better variable names and some comments:

```
for Month in {1..12}   # demo a whole year 
do 
    Year=2009
    LastBusinessDay=""
    (( Month = $Month + 1 ))    # use the beginning of the next month to find the end of the one we're interested in
    if [[ $Month = 13 ]]
    then
        Month=1
        (( Year++ ))
    fi;
    # these two calls to date could be combined and then parsed out
    # this first call is in "American" order, but could be changed - everything else is localized - I think
    LastDayofMonth=$(date -d "$Month/1/$Year -1 day")    # get the day before the first of the month
    DayofWeek=$(date -d "$LastDayofMonth" +%u)    # the math is easier than Sun=0 (%w)
    if [[ $DayofWeek = 6 || $DayofWeek = 7 ]]    # if it's Sat or Sun
    then
        (( Offset = 5 - $DayofWeek ))    # then make it Fri
        LastBusinessDay=$(date -d "$LastDayofMonth $Offset day")
    else
        LastBusinessDay=$LastDayofMonth
    fi
    echo "$LastDayofMonth - $DayofWeek - $LastBusinessDay"
done
```

Output:

```
Sat Jan 31 00:00:00 CST 2009 - 6 - Fri Jan 30 00:00:00 CST 2009
Sat Feb 28 00:00:00 CST 2009 - 6 - Fri Feb 27 00:00:00 CST 2009
Tue Mar 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 2 - Tue Mar 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Thu Apr 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 4 - Thu Apr 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Sun May 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 7 - Fri May 29 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Tue Jun 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 2 - Tue Jun 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 5 - Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 1 - Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 3 - Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Sat Oct 31 00:00:00 CDT 2009 - 6 - Fri Oct 30 00:00:00 CDT 2009
Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 CST 2009 - 1 - Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 CST 2009
Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 2009 - 4 - Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 2009
```

Note: I discovered during testing that if you try to use this for dates around World War II that it fails due to wartime time zones like CWT and CPT.

**Edit**: Here's a version that should run on AIX and other systems that can't use the above. It should work on Bourne, Bash, Korn and zsh.

```
function lbdN { cal $1 $2 | awk 'NF == 0 {next} FNR > 2 {week = $0} END {num = split(week, days); lbdN = days[num]; if ( num == 1 ) { lbdN -= 2 }; if ( num == 7 ) { lbdN-- }; print lbdN }'; }
```

You may have to make adjustments if your `cal` starts weeks on Monday.

Here's how you can use it:

```
month=12; year=2009    # if these are unset or null, the current month/year will be used
if [[ $(date +%d) == $(lbdN $month $year) ]]; 
then
    echo "Don't do stuff today"
else
    echo "It's not the last business day of the month"
fi
```

making appropriate adjustments for your shell's `if`...`then` syntax, of course.

**Edit**: *Bug Fix*: The previous version of `lbdN` failed when February ends on Saturday the 28th because of the way it used `tail`. The new version fixes that. It uses only `cal` and `awk`.

**Edit**: For completeness, I thought it would be handy to include functions for the first business day of the month.

Requires `date` with `-d`:

```
function fbdm { typeset dwn d; dwn=$(date -d "$1/1/$2" +%u); d=1; if [[ $dwn = 6 || $dwn = 7 ]]; then (( d = 9 - $dwn )); fi; echo $(date -d "$1/$d/$2"); }
```

For May 2010:

```
Mon May 3 00:00:00 CDT 2010
```

Requires `cal` and `awk` only:

```
function fbdN { cal $1 $2 | awk 'FNR == 3 { week = $0 } END { num = split(week, days); fbdN = days[1]; if ( num == 1 ) { fbdN += 2 }; if ( num == 7 ) { fbdN++ }; print fbdN }'; }
```

For August 2010:

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  I really appreciate your help.

Unfortunately, my "date" command does not support the -d option.  I'm running ksh on AIX 5.2.  

$ date -d "12/1/2009 -1 day"            
date: Not a recognized flag: d          
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"] $                                       

I'll still click on the check-mark since your solution clearly works on other systems, and I didn't list my OS in the initial question.

Comment: Hmmm... It took out my carriage returns when it posted my comment.  I guess I need to read the docs on how to format my comments.